# How to terminate a class with reference to parent?

Tags: excel, vba, memory-leaks

I've found out that class doesn't flush itself if you have a reference to parent within.
For example something like this:

```
Private Sub test()
    Dim a As New settings
    Dim b As New Collection
    b.Add a
    Set a = Nothing
End Sub
```

And in class 'settings':

```
Private SQLSettings As New settingsserver
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Me.SQLSettings.Initialize Parent:=Me
    MsgBox "init"
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    MsgBox "terminate"
End Sub
```

So basically if I remove Parent:=Me it will terminate settings class, but if I leave it, it will stay in garbage collector. Why is that? The class has a subclass with reference to that class so shouldn't it flush whole package? How can can you flush a class automatically with reference to a parent class?

Comment: First thing to do is to avoid `As New`, which makes an auto-instantiated object - if you added `Debug.Print a Is Nothing` under `Set a = Nothing`, you would find that it prints `False`

Comment: The question is why does referencing from SQLSettings to settings prevent termination of settings class... why all subclasses don't get terminated?

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no garbage collector, VBA is reference-counted, not garbage-collected.

If an object has >0 references, it doesn't get terminated. As a consequence, if one or more child objects are referencing a parent object, nulling the parent won't destroy any objects.

Also not helping, `Dim...As New` creates [auto-instantiated objects](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/SelfAssignedDeclaration) - you'll want to frantically avoid that.

Hard to tell where to plug it with so little code shown, but basically you need the child objects to explicitly `Set Parent = Nothing` at one point or another, **before** you try nulling the parent object.

If you're feeling adventurous you could side-step the issue using [WeakReferences](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/lazy-object-weak-reference/) (disclaimer: I wrote that article), but that may be a bit unstable or crash-prone.

Comment: I see. So basically I should make subroutines that brake references before removing objects...

Comment: @DamGal yup. Could be just the parent exposing a `Teardown` method that iterates all children and invokes their own `Teardown` method (recursively, if that's a tree structure).